# Blurry images, shifting content, unreproducable errors in IE9

Tags: html, css, image, blurry

I have a client who keeps sending me bugs that I can't replicate on any of my computers, but I also can't find anything about this particular problem online.

They are 1000 miles away, so I can't go see what their computer is like, and according to them, they don't have any addons installed and this is the screenshot of their IE9 about page:

[image]

Here's an example of one of them,

**This is what I see in IE9:**

[image]

**This is what THEY see in IE9:**

[image]

Not only is the bottom line missing in theirs, but that top little green arrow next to "Company History" is kinda blurry, even though it's the same exact image file as the other two that aren't blurry, and there isn't anything around it that could cover it up, plus I can't replicate this. I tried my home computer, my office one, and several in the IT department.

The code here is just a simple table (I have to use a table here, normally I wouldn't)

```
<table id="contentButtons" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td height="1"><img src="table-line.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><a href="#">COMPANY <strong>HISTORY</strong> <img src="arrow-right-orange.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="1"><img src="table-line.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><a href="#">SOCIAL <strong>ENGAGEMENT</strong> <img src="arrow-right-orange.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="1"><img src="table-line.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><a href="#"><strong>JOIN</strong> OUR TEAM <img src="arrow-right-orange.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="1"><img src="table-line.png"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is another example of a blurry background image, instead of an embedded image:

**This is what I see**
[image]

**This is what they see:**
[image]

In this case they are complaining that the top green line is blurry and different from the bottom line (it's a little hard to see here and it's also smaller than mine. I'm not sure if they are zoomed or the screenshot is just a tad smaller). Ignore the alignment and font issue, those are unrelated and fixed already since that picture was taken.

But that top line CANT be blurry, this is a sprite, there's nothing there to BE blurry. I thought maybe the top half of the sprite was spilling into the bottom half, but it isn't, there is a white line there, not green:

[image]

What could be causing this? I've never had a client come back to me before with all these display errors that I can't replicate.

Comment: What is their screen resolution?

Comment: Her's is 1920x1080 widescreen. However this particular element is above the "fold" at about 780px down.

My own screen resolutions are 1920x1200 and 1440x900 for my second monitor

Comment: Could they have an old cached copy of this page?  Maybe have them clear their cache.

Comment: We've tried that. I also know that they are getting the latest css and js because I've made some other changes to the site since this started that are showing through on their end.

Really what confuses me here is that line element isn't really anything but an image file inside of a table cell, and the other two that are identical to it show up just fine. They don't even really use CSS.

Comment: Is it possible they've somehow modified the browser or document mode from the developer tools?

Comment: You've got me on this one.  Don't think this is the issue, but maybe try closing image tags? `<img src="table-line.png"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions worth checking-up on:

- Update version matches (the "root" version might be the same, but be aware that patching Windows/IE might change its behaviour
- 32bit / 64bit (in the past I have come across very similar problems. The only approach I could rely on was changing the way it was implemented).
- as previously stated try eliminating/changing css, use inline css, or similar.
- IE9 has a developer mode that may help (F12). Try getting them to take a screenshot of the selected element.
- Maybe someone could give you a remote desktop connection via VNC, and check things out on the client's browser directly

I will update this if something else pops in my head.

Comment: Might be the update version. They are on an older one than I am. I have update version 9.0.12. Still strange, though. I mean this works in IE8.

Comment: I have version 9.0.14. Updates from MS are kinda unreliable.

Comment: just found this gem: http://www.ehow.com/how_4813512_fix-blurred-pictures-internet-explorer.html

Comment: Can you clarify to me what you mean by the bullet point: "32bit / 64bit (in the past I have come across very similar problems. The only approach I could rely on was changing the way it was implemented)."

Comment: Yes. I suppose you know how quirky IE is about a lot of things. In a development, at some point, I ran across a bug that was showing in a 64bit internet explorer, but worked fine on the 32bit version. Same blurring of the image. What was done to change that was putting an inline element as a background-image (that also cleared up the code). I might be mistaken but the quirky implementation was very similar to what you presented.

Comment: You could aslo try this: convert the table as a whole to a div, and <tr><td> to <ul><li> and try styling them in CSS separately.

Comment: @Stacey Garrison could you try to reproduce the problem code in jsBin (http://jsbin.com/) and post a link back?